# Insert more rows based on conditions from other rows

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

```
data have;
input year  firm_id location_id action  action_amount   operate new_entry
;
cards;
2013    28013   6085    1   10000   0   0
2015    28013   6085    1   12000   0   0
2015    28013   29189   1   10000   0   0
2016    28013   34019   1   5000    1   1
2017    28013   34019   0   0   1   2
2011    120609  9003    1   7000    0   0
2012    120609  9003    0   0   1   1
2013    120609  9003    1   5000    1   2
2012    247908  23001   1   9000    0   0
2013    247908  23001   1   8000    0   0
2014    247908  23001   1   8500    1   1
2015    247908  23001   0   0   1   2
2003    356123  1001    0   0   0   0
2004    356123  1001    0   0   0   0
2009    356123  1001    1   9800    1   1
;
run;
```

I want to add additional rows and two new variables called "pre_action" and "pre_action_amount" to obtain the following dataset:

```
    data want;
input year  firm_id location_id action  action_amount   operate new_entry   pre_action  pre_action_amount
;
cards;
2013    28013   6085    1   10000   0   0   .   .
2014    28013   6085    0   0   0   0   1   10000
2015    28013   6085    1   12000   0   0   .   .
2016    28013   6085    0   0   0   0   1   12000
2015    28013   29189   1   6500    0   0   .   .
2016    28013   29189   0   0   0   0   1   6500
2016    28013   34019   1   5000    1   1   0   0
2017    28013   34019   0   0   1   2   .   .
2011    120609  9003    1   7000    0   0   .   .
2012    120609  9003    0   0   1   1   1   7000
2013    120609  9003    1   5000    1   2   .   .
2012    247908  23001   1   9000    0   0   .   .
2013    247908  23001   1   8000    0   0   1   9000
2014    247908  23001   1   8500    1   1   1   8000
2015    247908  23001   0   0   1   2   .   .
2003    356123  1001    0   0   0   0   .   .
2004    356123  1001    0   0   0   0   0   0
2005    356123  1001    0   0   0   0   0   0
2009    356123  1001    1   9800    1   1   0   0
;
run;
```

The rules are as follows:

1) First, consider only the rows with operate = 0.

- For each firm_id and location_id pair, if in the following year there is no row with the same firm_id and location_id, then create a new row with the following year and same firm_id and location_id pair. The variables action, action_amount, operate, and new_entry are all set to 0, while pre_action and pre_action_amount is set to be the value of action and action_amount in the previous year. Example: In year 2013, for the firm_id/location_id pair 28013/6085, we have operate = 0. But in 2014, there are no observations for this firm_id/location_id pair. So we set action, action_amount, operate, and new_entry to be 0 and pre_action=1 and pre_action_amount=10000 which are the values for action and action_amount in 2013.
- For each firm_id and location_id pair, if in the following year there is a row with the same firm_id and location_id, then simply set pre_action and pre_action_amount to be the value of action and action_amount in the previous year. Example: In year 2011 for firm_id/location_id 120609/9003, we have operate=0. But in the next year 2012, there is a row with this firm_id/location_id pair. So we set pre_action=1 and pre_action_amount=7000 which are the values for action and action_amount in 2011. Another example is in year 2003, for the firm_id/location_id 356123/1001.

2) Now consider the rows with new_entry=1 that do not yet have a value of pre_action and pre_action_amount. Set both pre_action and pre_action_amount to be 0.

3) All other values of pre_action and pre_action_amount are empty.

I am unsure of how to create these new rows given the complicated rules above, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve this problem yourself and update your question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your main problem is how to access information from the next record to determine if there is a gap in `year` (as there is no `lead()` function in SAS), following is an example that shows the use of the `POINT=` option of the `SET` statement to do precisely that.

The example is based on a slightly modified version of your data since:

- it reduces the number of observations and variables in the dataset.
- it uses just one variable to define the observation ID.

Example code:

```
/* Example that shows how to use the POINT= option of the SET statement
   to look ahead at the next observation and decide whether there is a gap in YEAR. */
data example;
    input year id action_amount;
    cards;
2013    28013    10000
2015    28013    12000 
2016    28013    5000  
2017    28013    0  
2003    356123   250   
2004    356123   320   
2009    356123   9800  
;
run;

* Observations should be sorted by ID and YEAR for the next data step;
proc sort data=example; by id year; run;

* Process
data example_filled;
    set example;
    by id year;

    * Create the variable that will be used in the POINT= option of the SET statement
    * to retrieve information from the next observation;
    _next_obs = _N_ + 1;

    * Compute variables storing values from the previous observation;
    retain pre_action_amount;
    pre_action_amount = lag(action_amount);
    if first.id then
        call missing(pre_action_amount);

    * Analyze possible YEAR gaps in a BY group and partly fill them;
    if last.id then do;
        *** No gaps to check => simply output the last observation of the BY group;
        output;
    end;
    else do;
        *** We should check for gaps in YEAR;
        * 1) Send the current observation to the output dataset;
        output;

        * 2) Check if there is a gap > 1 based on the YEAR value from the next observation,
        * and if so, fill in (just) ONE observation
        * Note the use of the POINT= option of the SET statement to access info from next obs;
        set example(keep=year rename=(year=next_year)) POINT=_next_obs;
        if next_year > year + 1 then do;
            * Compute pre action values as the action values of the obs just output above;
            * All the other variables still maintain their values and will be carried over
            * this newly created obs;
            pre_action_amount = action_amount;
            year = year + 1;
            * Output the filled observation;
            output;
        end;
    end;

    drop next_year;
run;
```

Expected output dataset `example_filled` (the new filled observations are Obs = 2 and Obs = 8):

```
                                        action_    pre_action_
                 Obs    year      id       amount       amount

                  1     2013     28013     10000            .
                  2     2014     28013     10000        10000
                  3     2015     28013     12000        10000
                  4     2016     28013      5000        12000
                  5     2017     28013         0         5000
                  6     2003    356123       250            .
                  7     2004    356123       320          250
                  8     2005    356123       320          320
                  9     2009    356123      9800          320
```

You may find handy to use this example as a basis to implement the logic you described in order to compute `pre_action` and `pre_action_amount`.

Note: here are other ways to access information from the next observation in a data step:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/06/19/can-you-lag-and-lead-at-the-same-time-if-using-the-sas-data-step-yes-you-can/